# Scripting Dictionary value(0) generates subscript out of range error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Master.xlsx. I have a two variables **startd** and **endd** that define date range I should be storing in my dictionary.

I have the list of holidays I am trying to remove from the dictionary in a separate worksheet.

```
    Set hld = Sheet2.Range("A2:A7")
    ....
    ....
    Dim WDdict As New Scripting.dictionary
    For n = startd To endd:  WDdict(n) = 1:  Next
    For Each hd In hld
        If hd > 0 Then hd = DateValue(hd): If WDdict.Exists(hd) Then WDdict.Remove (hd)
    Next
```

"Base" is the name of one of the worksheets. This "Base" sheet has two key columns - Email and Date of Joining (DOJ)

```
    EmlsrcA = Application.Transpose(src.Sheets("Base").Range("A2:A" & rowsn))
    DojsrcA = Application.Transpose(src.Sheets("Base").Range("G2:G" & rowsn))
```

**What I want to do**

If DOJ value for every row is after / later than the startd (input parameter) then remove every date between startd and DOJ from the dictionary.

I tried

```
For Each emls In EmlsrcA 'each line in email in base page

    Dim WDdictrs As New Scripting.dictionary
    For Each elm In WDdict: WDdictrs(elm) = 1: Next

    remove dates before doj
    dj = 0
    If DojsrcA(dj) > startd Then
        dj = dj + 1
        For n = startd To DojsrcA(dj):
            If WDdictrs.Exists(n) Then WDdictrs.Remove (n) Else WDdictrs(n) = 1
        Next
    End If
```

It throws

> subscript out of range

on `If DojsrcA(dj) > startd Then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DojsrcA is a base 1 two dimensions array of Variants from the Range object. 
Your variable dj = 0, so it's out of range started with 1.

Comment: Yes, this was so stupid of me. I figured it out while debugging and then saw your answer. Thank you!